# Java Make declare and initialize 2d array of my object

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception

I am working on making a program that makes a grid of a random size >1 and then randomly puts walls inside the maze. The program is then supposed to find a route from the starting point to the goal. I am using a breadth search.

my problem is that I could not find a way to store coordinates so I made my own class `Coord` that has an x and y value. for part of my algorithm I need to make a 2d array of type `Coord`

I cannot seem to get it to work, every time I try to run the program I get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't know why or how to allocate this array and It is needed for my algorithm.

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
Coord[][] test2dArray = new Coord[3][3];
test2dArray = Coord.make2dArray(3, 3);
```

This is calling:

```
public class Coord {
int x;
int y;


public static Coord[][] make2dArray(int sizex, int sizey){
    Coord[][] array= new Coord[sizex][sizey];
    for(int x=0; x<sizex; x++){
        for(int y=0; x<sizey; y++){
            array[x][y] = new Coord(0,0);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

So far I do have a 1d array working with this code:

```
Coord[] testArray = Coord.makeArray(4);
```

Which is calling:

```
public static Coord[] makeArray(int size){
    Coord[] array= new Coord[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        array[i]= new Coord(0,0);
    }
    return array;

}
```

If you could help me and explain what is going on that would be great! Thanks so much for all your help :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  rather than a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
for(int y=0; x<sizey; y++)
```

should be

```
for(int y=0; y<sizey; y++)
```

The condition `y<sizey` is needed to stop `y` being too large and causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Your typo means that `y` is not stopped.

Comment: it was a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` my bad for listing the wrong exception

Comment: is there a more concise way to use this code?
`Coord[][] test2dArray = new Coord[3][3]; 
test2dArray = Coord.make2dArray(3, 3);`